# Parse a formatted string with multiple delimiters into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, text-parsing

I am using a module to create booking orders in my website.

They have a hook I can use which fires after a new booking is created.

The variable I get is booking_form:
Inside this variable is the following:

```
text^name1^PETER~text^secondname1^SMITH~text^phone1^023482348~text^adres1^STREETAVENUE 1B~text^postcode1^91201CA~text^woonplaats1^LIVINGPLACE~email^email1^peter@example.com
```

Is there someway in PHP to get all the values of all the fields in an array or something? So something like this?

```
array(
    name or name1? => PETER,
    secondname => SMITH,
    etc... => etc...
)
```

So the function has to split the string based on the ^ and ~ characters.

Comment: There is an obvious pattern to use for `explode`: split by `~` to get form inputs, split by `^` to get `group => field => value`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$result = array();
$data = explode ( "~", $yourString )
foreach ( $data as $element)
{
    $elt = explode ( "^", $element ) ;
    $result[$elt[1]] = $elt[2];
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this...

```
$input = 'text^name1^PETER~text^secondname1^SMITH~text^phone1^023482348~text^adres1^STREETAVENUE 1B~text^postcode1^91201CA~text^woonplaats1^LIVINGPLACE~email^email1^peter@example.com';

$split = explode('~', $input);
$finalArray = [];

foreach($split as $thing) {
    list ($type, $key, $value) = explode('^', $thing);
    $finalArray[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatted string seems inconsistently formatted and I don't understand the relevance of the `text` and `email` markers.

Furthermore, we don't know your input data may vary because you only gave us one and string AND we don't know your exact desired output because you "yatta-yatta"ed what you expect.

That said, parsing the string can be done with regex.

- Match the text or email label followed by a literal caret
- Capture one or more non-caret characters
- Match a literal caret
- Capture zero or more non-caret/non-tilde characters

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gEie6))

```
$string = 'text^name1^PETER~text^secondname1^SMITH~text^phone1^023482348~text^adres1^STREETAVENUE 1B~text^postcode1^91201CA~text^woonplaats1^LIVINGPLACE~email^email1^peter@example.com';

preg_match_all('/(?:text|email)\^([^^]+)\^([^^~]*)/', $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_export(
    array_column($matches, 2, 1)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'name1' => 'PETER',
  'secondname1' => 'SMITH',
  'phone1' => '023482348',
  'adres1' => 'STREETAVENUE 1B',
  'postcode1' => '91201CA',
  'woonplaats1' => 'LIVINGPLACE',
  'email1' => 'peter@example.com',
)
```